# C++ Reading values of LPCVOID pointer

Tags: c++, kernel32, detours

I have a hook on kernel32.dll's Writefile command. The hook is being triggered, however, I am not able to read the buffer contents.

**Goal:** Msgbox shows the contents of the buffer being sent to the com port.

**Issue:** The msgbox is printing a seemingly-random series of numbers, which I am assuming is the memory address, instead of the actual contents of lpBuffer.

**C++ code:**

```
void hookedFunc(HANDLE hfile, LPCVOID * lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberBytesToWrite, LPWORD lpNumberofBytesWritten, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped) {

    char *pString = reinterpret_cast<char *>(lpBuffer);

    //Msgbox - arg 1//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    WCHAR szTest[45];
    swprintf_s(szTest, 45, L"%d|\n", pString);
    MessageBox(NULL, szTest, L"BUFFER CONTENTS", MB_OK);
    swprintf_s(szTest, 45, L"%d", nNumberBytesToWrite);
    MessageBox(NULL, szTest, L"TEST", MB_OK);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPCVOID is a pointer (to a constant), lpBuffer is a pointer to that pointer. I imagine

```
const char* pString = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(*lpBuffer);
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, `szTest` will contain garbage because

```
swprintf_s(szTest, 45, L"%d|\n", pString);
```

says interpret `pString` as an integer (thanks to `%d`) and convert that integer to ascii and store it at `szTest`

So yes, you're printing an address, but possibly only part of it.

## Addendum:

Captain Giraffe's answer points out another bug: You're looking at the wrong place for the string.

Comment: Changing %d to %s causes the program to crash

Comment: @user1698144 Couple reasons for that. One's the bug Captain Giraffe points out in their answer, and the other is the `_s` functions default to aborting the program if the input is bad rather than trying to limp on after undefined behaviour. You have two bugs, not one.

Comment: Well, the sole purpose of the program is to find that value. After implementing Griaffe's fix, the msgbox does output, but it is all gibberish.Looks like the same Chinese character repeated over and over

Comment: Time to fire up the debugger and see what's really going on. What is in that buffer? Seeing as it is a pointer to a pointer are you sure that something is supposed to be there? Usually when you see a pointer to a pointer as a parameter, the function is expected to supply a pointer for someone else.

Comment: The buffer is supposed to contain a command to the serial port(0x0A, 0xA0, 0x50, 0x05). Looking at the pointer in VS debugger, shows it is pointing to the mem address 0x0c5cdb20. The issue seems to be with my casting and  output to the msgbox?

Comment: Edit: Looking a the memory in debug, everything is correct. the writetofile function I am hooking writes to a log file, before it writes to the comport.